# Rails ActiveRecord query for most recent viewed resources

Tags: ruby, database-design, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I recently made the following models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :resources
  has_many :resource_views, :through => :user_resource_views, :source => 'Resource'
end

class Resource < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :resource_views, :through => :user_resource_views, :source => 'Resource'
end

class UserResourceView < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :resource_id, :user_id
  belongs_to :resource
  belongs_to :user_id
end
```

Now, I want my home#index action to set @resources to the current_user's most recently viewed resources. How would you advise I proceed? Perhaps something similar to current_user.resource_views.find(:all, :order => 'created_at')?

In SQL, I would do something like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Resource 
WHERE id IN (SELECT * FROM UserResourceView WHERE user_id = current_user.id)
```

... but then the ORDER BY created_at, hmmm

I'll be periodically adding progress updates throughout the day until I figure it out.

Comment: What version of Rails are you using? The `find(:all, :order => 'created_at')` looks a little like Rails 2.x?

Comment: Yikes, so, I'm using 3.2.11. I am just beginning to familiarize myself with best practices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given you're on Rails 3.x, what you're looking for is probably something like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :resources
  has_many :resource_views, :class_name => 'UserResourceView'
  has_many :viewed_resources, :through => :resource_views, :source => :resource

  def recently_viewed_resources
    viewed_resources.order('user_resource_views.created_at DESC')
  end
end

class Resource < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :resource_views, :class_name => 'UserResourceView'
end

class UserResourceView < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :resource_id, :user_id
  belongs_to :resource
  belongs_to :user_id
end
```

And to access the collection in your controller:

```
current_user.recently_viewed_resources
```

Comment: Just noticed I mixed up the naming of the associations. Fixed it!

Comment: Thinking about it, that doesn't really work the way you want it to. It's hard to come up with a good solution without the possibility to test it ;) I'm thinking about it a little more and will edit the answer.